# How do "arrays" work in assembly / How to allocate a block of memory in asm?

Tags: assembly, masm

I am currently learning the basics of x86-64 assembly with MASM (and VS). When I want a block of memory thats 5 bytes big I can just do:

```
.data
    myVar byte 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

However how do I get a block of memory that is `n` `bytes` (or `qwords`) long without having to manually type n numbers in the variable definition (in this case `1, 2, 3, 4, 5`)?

Comment: If `n` is a runtime value, use a memory allocation function of your OS or use the stack (for small `n` and if scope permits). If it is compile time value, you can use an assembler construct such as `100 dup (0)`

Comment: If you submit your comment as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you @Jester, you answered my question. This works:

```
myVar byte 100 dup(0)
```

Comment: Yes, that works.  The approach there is to over allocate, and hope it is enough memory for the problem at hand, which it often will be for toy things like assignments.  In real-world programming, though, there is often no single `n` that is large enough for all possible scenarios, so dynamic memory allocation with checking for allocation failure is better; doing this, the program will try until it runs out of memory.  Of course, in the overallocation approach, you can still prevent buffer overruns by checking to be sure not to go over 100 (in that example).

Comment: It very much depends on the system. Is your program the only program running on it or are there others? How large is the total memory compared to your maximum needs? Is there an operating system?